# Check if String has only Integers separated by comma in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am really empty at Regex side and that's why couldn't get how to make a Regex in PHP which checks if the string has this particular sequence of characters.

```
$str = '2323,321,329,34938,23123,54545,123123,312312';
```

Means to check if the string contains only Integers (Not decimal, no alphabats or anything else) separated by comma (,).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
'/^\d+(?:,\d+)*$/'
```

**Code:**

```
$re = '/^\d+(?:,\d+)*$/';
$str = '2323,321,329,34938,23123,54545,123123,312312'; 

if ( preg_match($re, $str) )
    echo "correct format";
else
    echo "incorrect format";
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun with no regex:

```
var_dump(
    !array_diff($a = explode(',', $str), array_map('intval', $a))
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not care about the format then you can just check for the characters:

```
$regex = '/^[0-9,]+$/';
if (preg_match($regex, $str) === 1) {
    echo 'Matches!';
}
```

You can also do it without using regular expressions:

```
$str = str_replace(',', '', $str);
if (ctype_digit($str)) {
    echo 'Matches!';
}
```

If you care about the format then something like this would work:

```
$regex = '/^[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*$/';
if (preg_match($regex, $str) === 1) {
    echo 'Matches!';
}
```