# How to check explode contain only comma separated values...?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

How to check that php explode hold only comma separated integer values.

for example i have a

```
$str= '10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100';
$arr = explode(',',$str);
```

and i want to check if the value in $str is 10,20,30 and so on. and cannot contain any of string and words.

I basically populate a drop-down from this $arr and i want to make check if user enter integer values with comma then its show the dropdown else if user enter any other format.

i also use `is_int` or `is_numeric` but it cannot solve my problem.

thanks for advance .

Comment: what error you are getting when you use is_int or is_numeric?

Comment: @JoneDotosvky if some one enter $str = '10a,20b,30c,40'; it also return true.

Comment: @TehseenAhmed  `is_numeric()` will work perfectly. check the examples i have given below

Comment: is_numeric should work.

Comment: @JoneDotosvky and what if some one add in $str= '10a,20c,30,40'; is only return first two false but i want to check whole array

Comment: see this posthttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206329/check-if-string-has-only-integers-separated-by-comma-in-php

Comment: set some kind of flag as false. whenever you get string set it as true.

Comment: @JoneDotosvky   the link i have shared right now is the perfect answer for his question

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is ctype_digit

```
$str= '10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100';
$arr = explode(',',$str);
foreach($arr as $a){
  if(!ctype_digit($a)){
    //Not an int
  }else{
    //is an int
  }
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/734431

Reference:- http://php.net/ctype_digit

Comment: https://eval.in/734414

Comment: https://eval.in/734417

Comment: @Kaylined what if i used a letter a with  $str= '10a,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100';  it also return wrong result ..

Comment: It returns the correct result, even if you add letters. https://eval.in/734431